# Windows Server 2012 R2 hosting related issue

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, windows-server-2012-r2, iis-8.5

I have hosted my website on windows server r2 (iis 8.5). 
It is working fine on server but I am not able to access this site from my local computer.

Please tell me how to make it accessible from my local computer.

Comment: What is the error message ?

Comment: "This webpage is not available" this is the message.

Comment: Check firewall settings and open the ports.